# angular controllers - two way broadcasting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, broadcast

I have a controller that wraps ui-router and control its flow (like menu bar).
when a user press on a menu item, there is a function that changes the ui-router state and broadcast an event to the inner controllers. 
every inner controller inside this ui-router can listen and act to this event.
the inner controllers are making validation on this event but if the validation fails I cannot undo the state change.
Any idea how to solve this problem?
Thanks

**update**:
using the ui-router $stateChangeStart event is a good approach but still incomplete.
now the problem is,
my main controller that hosts the ui-router and the menu bar has a progress bar.
The main controller is registered to $stateChangeStart and taking care of the progress bar, but the child view that is also register to the event is preventing default. which means the controllers are now in an inconsistent mode. the main controller has already took care of the progress bar and the view itself did not changed.
Please advise

Comment: You can add listener for stateChange start event and change the state only when your conditions are satified (put the validation in stateChange start event handler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ui-router` itself issues a `$stateChangeStart` event.

Your controllers can use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the transition from happening.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        if (notOK ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        };
})
```

For more information see, [UI-Router state.$state API Reference -- events - $stateChangeStart](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#events_$statechangestart)

Comment: well, I was happy too early :) now I am facing another issue. I have two controllers that registered to this event. the main(with the menus) and the child view, when the child view triggers preventDefault, it wont stop the parent function to do its work, now I am in an inconsistent state when the main controller has change his state but the child controller preventDefault. is there a solution for this as well? thanks

Comment: I found the solution, I moved the main controller work to the $stateChangeSuccess event. big thanks to everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast a cancellation event using `$rootScope` and catch the event inside your menu controller.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('cancelStateChange');
```